# How to Template a Bitshifter

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm trying to create a bitshifter which initialises

I'm trying to create a template that allows the user to define something to bitshift. The other classes defined here just allow the user to read from an input and write to an output, an example looks like this:

The bitshifter I've started writing looks like this though I'm a little stuck and just need a few ideas to get me going again

```
  template<typename T >
    class Bitshifter :
    {
        public:
          Bitshifter(T val) : memory_(val)
        {
        }

        ~Bitshifter() {}

        virtual void Tick( T input)
        {
              std::cout << (memory_ << 1 | input) << std::endl;
        }

    private:
            T memory_;
    };
}


Bitshifter<uint32_t> myComponent<0>;
myComponent.Tick(1);//
myComponent.Tick(0);//
```

So it should produce:

```
0x1
0x2
```

It would be quite nice to be able to use a few different types such as:

`std::bitset<N>` and `uint64_t`

But I'd also like to use values if possible that I have defined in a class such as:

```
template<size_t N>
class std_logic_vector
{
public:
  typedef std::bitset<N> std_logic_vector_t;


public:
  std_logic_vector() :
    std_logic_vector_ (0)
  {}

  std_logic_vector(
           std_logic_vector_t value
           ):
std_logic_vector_ (value)
  {}

  ~std_logic_vector(){}

  std_logic_vector_t value() const {return std_logic_vector_;}

private:
  std_logic_vector_t std_logic_vector_;
};
```

Then I could use:

```
Bitset<std_logic_vector<32>>(std_logic_vector<32>())
```

But it fails when trying to do the bitshift operation.

Comment: Ehm...what?
I kind of understand your question but your examples (1) too complex, (2) badly formatted and (3) don't really show your problem.
Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: simplified, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code pretty much already does exactly what you want.
I adjusted it a little bit and added some examples.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T >
class Bitshifter
{
public:
    Bitshifter(T val) 
        :memory_(val)
    {
    }

    ~Bitshifter() {}

    virtual void Tick(T input)
    {
        memory_ <<= 1;
        memory_ |= input;
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << memory_ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T memory_;
};


int main()
{
    Bitshifter<uint32_t> myComponent1(0);
    myComponent1.Tick(1);//
    myComponent1.Tick(0);//

    Bitshifter<uint64_t> myComponent2(0);
    myComponent2.Tick(1);//
    myComponent2.Tick(0);//

    Bitshifter<std::bitset<10>> myComponent3(0x01);
    myComponent3.Tick(0x01);
    myComponent3.Tick(0x00);


}
```

Output:

```
0x1
0x2
0x1
0x2
0x0000000011
0x0000000110
```

Comment: So having simplified it as you asked, I narrowed down the problem. Is it possible to use a class as an argument as I have shown above or not?

Comment: @fiz I guess you mean `Bitshifter<std_logic_vector<32>> shifter(std_logic_vector<32>(0x0));` instead of `Bitset<std_logic_vector<32>>(std_logic_vector<32>())`?

The problem with this is, that your `std_logic_vector` class does not define `operator<<=(size_t)` and `operator|=(size_t)`.

Also passing an object of this type to `std::cout` using `operator<<` is not supported by the type.
These are requirements of `Bitshifter`.

You have now 2 possibilities: Implement a specialized version of `Bitshifter` for `std_logic_vector` or add the missing functions to `std_logic_vector`

Comment: Even if I do that, I can't seem to pass a class into this bitshifter template as the bitwise operators don't work on it

Comment: @fiz As long as the class you pass doesn't provide any shifting (or at least access to the member that should be shifted) what you want to do is impossible. What do you expect the compiler to do? Automatically detect that your `std_logic_vector` has some `std::bitset` as member and shift this member even as it's private? That can't work.